# Turning a dictionary with seriesinfo object into a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to turn this dictionary with two keys and the values containing a list of tuples:

```
{'HNOMSLQ027S': SeriesInfo(id='HNOMSLQ027S', realtime_start='2023-10-12', realtime_end='2023-10-12', title='Households and Nonprofit Organizations; Municipal Securities; Asset, Transactions', observation_start='1946-10-01', observation_end='2023-04-01', frequency='Quarterly', frequency_short='Q', units='Millions of Dollars', units_short='Mil. of $', seasonal_adjustment='Seasonally Adjusted Annual Rate', seasonal_adjustment_short='SAAR', last_updated='2023-09-08 11:48:04-05', popularity=1, notes='Source ID: FA153062005.Q\n\nFor more information about the Flow of Funds tables, see the Financial Accounts Guide (https://www.federalreserve.gov/apps/fof/Default.aspx).\n\nWith each quarterly release, the source may make major data and structural revisions to the series and tables. These changes are available in the Release Highlights (https://www.federalreserve.gov/apps/fof/FOFHighlight.aspx).\n\nIn the Financial Accounts, the source identifies each series by a string of patterned letters and numbers. For a detailed description, including how this series is constructed, see the series analyzer (https://www.federalreserve.gov/apps/fof/SeriesAnalyzer.aspx?s=FA153062005&t=) provided by the source.'), 'HOOREVLMHMV': SeriesInfo(id='HOOREVLMHMV', realtime_start='2023-10-12', realtime_end='2023-10-12', title='Households; Owner-Occupied Real Estate Including Vacant Land and Mobile Homes at Market Value, Market Value Levels', observation_start='1945-10-01', observation_end='2023-04-01', frequency='Quarterly', frequency_short='Q', units='Billions of Dollars', units_short='Bil. of $', seasonal_adjustment='Not Seasonally Adjusted', seasonal_adjustment_short='NSA', last_updated='2023-09-08 11:43:04-05', popularity=33, notes='Source ID: LM155035015.Q\n\nFor more information about the Flow of Funds tables, see the Financial Accounts Guide (https://www.federalreserve.gov/apps/fof/Default.aspx).\n\nWith each quarterly release, the source may make major data and structural revisions to the series and tables. These changes are available in the Release Highlights (https://www.federalreserve.gov/apps/fof/FOFHighlight.aspx).\n\nIn the Financial Accounts, the source identifies each series by a string of patterned letters and numbers. For a detailed description, including how this series is constructed, see the series analyzer (https://www.federalreserve.gov/apps/fof/SeriesAnalyzer.aspx?s=LM155035015&t=) provided by the source.')}
```

Into a data frame that looks like this:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Your values aren't lists of tuples, they're `SeriesInfo` objects.

Comment: Is there a way to turn a `SeriesInfo` to a dictionary? `pd.DataFrame()` can convert a dict of dicts to a df.

Comment: What is `SeriesInfo`? Do you have a link to the documentation?

Comment: Looks like this: https://pyfredapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/series.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `SeriesInfo` is derived from [`pydantic.BaseModel`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/base_model/#pydantic.main.BaseModel.model_dump). This class has a method to dump a dictionary, `BaseModel.model_dump()`.

I do not have the setup to test this, but the idea would be:

```
src_dict = {
    'HNOMSLQ027S': SeriesInfo(
        id='HNOMSLQ027S', 
        realtime_start='2023-10-12', 
        realtime_end='2023-10-12', ...),
    'HOOREVLMHMV': SeriesInfo(
        id='HOOREVLMHMV',
        realtime_start='2023-10-12',
        realtime_end='2023-10-12', ...),
}

dst_dict = {k, v.model_dump() for k, v in src_dict.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame(dst_dict)
```